# How does Luabind work?

Tags: function, lua, wrapper, bind

I'm interested on how Luabind wrapper make it possible to pass a function without the `lua_State *L` and not using the Lua stack.

How does Luabind:

1. count the function parameters?
2. link the function parameters to Lua stack?
3. link those classes

I'm not trying to create another binding like Luabind to other libraries. I'm just wondering how did they do that. Just a curious man.

Answer (score 14):

Good question. I had some vague idea of how luabind does what it does, but I didn't know enough to answer fully and accurately. Armed with an IDE and debugger I started dissecting the following very simple piece:

```
struct C
{
    int i;
    int f(int x, const char* s)
};

    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();

open(L);
module(L)
[
    class_<C>("C")
        .def_readwrite("index", &C::i)
        .def("f", &C::f)
];
```

First thing to notice is that `L` is passed to luabind a lot, the call to `open` creates a few globals in the Lua state: the `__luabind_classes` of type userdata and two functions `class` and `property`. Luabind doesn't seem to use global variables - everything it needs is saved in the lua environment.

Now we get to `module(L)[...]`. The original code is the best explanation, first here's `module`:

```
inline module_ module(lua_State* L, char const* name = 0)
{
    return module_(L, name);
}
```

Simple enough, here's `module_`:

```
class LUABIND_API module_
{
public:
    module_(lua_State* L_, char const* name);
    void operator[](scope s);

private:
    lua_State* m_state;
    char const* m_name;
};
```

So what our little program does is call operator [] on the `module_` class with some definitions (that's the `scope` parameter), but the `module_` class knows in which Lua state to operate. The `scope` class is also interesting to look at (some parts are omitted and some slightly simplified):

```
struct LUABIND_API scope
{
    //...
    explicit scope(detail::registration* reg);
    scope& operator,(scope s);
    void register_(lua_State* L) const;
private:
    detail::registration* m_chain;
};
```

`scope` is building a linked list of `detail::registration` nodes, that list comes from using `operator,`. So when one does `module(L) [class_<...>..., class_<...>...]`, `class_` which inherits from `scope` initializes its base with a `detail::registration` instance, then the comma operator of `scope` builds a linked list of all registrations, this is passed to `module_::operator[]` which calls `scope::register_` which in turn enumerates the chain and calls `register_` on all those `detail::registration` objects. The `lua_State` is always passed to `register_`.

Phew. Now let's see what happens when one does `class_<C>("C").def("f", &C::f)`. This constructs an instance of `class_<C>` with a certain name which goes in the `detail::registration` member in `class_`. Calling the `class_::def` method writes in the reg structure and whatnot, but here's a very interesting line deeper in the call chain from `def`:

```
            object fn = make_function(
                L, f, deduce_signature(f, (Class*)0), policies);
```

Oooh, `deduce_signature`, I really wanted to see that. Now I want to unsee it, but the way it works is this: through dark preprocessor sorcery aided by boost ([`BOOST_PP_ITERATE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/iterate.html) and some other utilities) the following is generated for each N between one and LUABIND_MAX_ARITY:

```
template <class R, class T, class A1, classA2, ..., classAN>
boost::mpl::vectorN_PLUS_2<R, T, A1, A2, ..., AN>  // type of return value
     deduce_signature(R(T::*)(A1, A2, ..., AN))
     {
          return boost::mpl::vectorN_PLUS_2<R, T, A1, A2, ..., AN>()
     }
```

Again, a function like this is generated for all N between 1 and LUABIND_MAX_ARITY which is 10 by default. There are a couple of overloads to handle const methods, virtual wrappers and free functions and such, which means that there are around 50 `deduce_signature` functions that end up in your sources just after the preprocessor and before compilation has started. From there, it's compiler's job to choose the right `deduce_signature` overload for the functions you pass to `def` and that will return the correct [`boost::mpl::vectorX`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/vector.html) type. From there `make_function` can do anything - it has a [compile time] list of parameter types and through some more template magic these are counted, converted to and from Lua values and so on.

This is where I will stop. Investigation is based on Luabind 0.8.1. Feel free to browse/debug Luabind's code for more answers - it takes some time but it is not that hard after you get used to the style :) Good luck.

**TL;DR:** Magic... black magic

Answer (score 3):

`luabind` has templated wrapper functions for the familiar `int luafunction(lua_State* L)` prototype which the C API accepts. In essence, the lua_CFunction is created for you. The actual C or C++ function to call can be stored as an upvalue to the wrapper. In the case of a C++ member function, the `this` pointer can be taken from the first argument.

Example code wrapping a C function using upvalues:

```
template<typename R, typename T1>
int arg1wrapper(lua_State* L)
{
    typedef R (*F)(T1);
    F func = (F)lua_touserdata(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    R retValue = func(luaToC<T1>(L, 1));
    push(L, retValue);
    return 1;
}

// example use
template<typename R, typename T1>
void push(R (*func)(T1))
{
    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, func);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, &arg1wrapper<R, T1>, 1);
}
```

(The `luaToC` templated function would be specialized for every C and C++ type the library intends to support. The `push` function would be overloaded similarily.)

You will notice that the above pair of functions will work for only one particular kind of C function; functions with a non-void return value and a single parameter. Void returns can be easily handled by factoring the return value operations into a third template specialized for void, but to support other amounts of parameters, you need a bunch of overloads. luabind does this: it has one overload for every amount of parameters it supports, including one for 0 parameters (the maximum amount is some arbitrary number they chose).

(note that in C++0x you can use variadic templates to support any amount of parameters with the same template)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `luabind`, but the whole idea of a "wrapper" is that it's built on top of some lower level abstraction, encapsulating it. `luabind` almost certainly *does* use `lua_State` *internally*.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html#basic-usage):

> The first thing you need to do is to call `luabind::open(lua_State*)` which will register the functions to create classes from Lua, and initialize some state-global structures used by luabind.

So my (somewhat educated) guess is that you do the `luabind::open` thing and it caches the state for use in the remaining functions.  (The clue lies in "initialize some state-global structures".)